# Изменять график при значениях

Tags: python, matplotlib

Есть синусоида, мне нужно чтоб при `y < 0` `linestyle = '-.'`, я предполагаю что нужно использовать `where=`, однако из за своей абсолютной некомпетентности в `matplotlib` я пробуя ничего не добился. Документация ничего не прояснила.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x3 = np.arange(-100*np.pi, 100*np.pi, 0.01)
y3 = np.sin(x3*0.03)
n = plt.plot(x3, y3)

plt.setp(n, where = (y3 < 0), linestyle = '-.')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используется [подход отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31345770/15035314) и вариант вызова метода `plot([x], y, [fmt], [x2], y2, [fmt2], ..., **kwargs)` из [matplotlib.pyplot.plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html).
В документации на [matplotlib.pyplot.setp](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.setp.html) аргументов, позволяющих определять условия применения стилей в зависимости от данных, не обнаружил.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x3 = np.arange(-100 * np.pi, 100 * np.pi, 0.01)
y3 = np.sin(x3 * 0.03)
plt.plot(x3, np.where(y3 < 0, np.nan, y3), 'b-', x3, np.where(y3 >= 0, np.nan, y3), 'b-.')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]